# Design question for not nullable enum and data with null values

Tags: .net, oop, design-patterns, database-design, model

In my web application I use a model with an Enum property. For example:

```
public class SomeObject 
{
   public Guid ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Color Color { get; set; }
}
public enum Color 
{
     blue,
     red
}
```

Color is a required field form.   Using EF Core based on that model created a table where the Color column not null.

However, some of the historic data I'm trying to import into the table does null values for Color.

From the design stand point, what should be a better solution:

1. Change the model to make Color nullable and add extra validation on the UI and inside APIs to prevent null values.
2. Add null value to Enum itself.
3. Assign some default value to the imported data with null Color.

I don't like any of these options, but what would be the best one in terms of design?

Comment: A default value is the least invasive, because it changes neither the model nor the enum; but ultimately this question is opinion-based and the answer will vary case by case.

Answer (score 0):

The records with `null` in the `Color` column effectively represents objects of unknown colours. Therefore, the obvious thing to do is to add an `Unknown` value to the enum `Color`. Then change the front-end to allow these objects to be displayed but not saved with the color set to 'unknown'.